# How do I calculate the length of an episode and it's sequential number in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a dataframe where I have sequential time data for an animal moving around in a room. I have a column denoting when the animal is immobile (isImmobile = TRUE or FALSE) and I would like to create a new column showing the duration of the immobile episodes - in the below example it would be 3 frames - so I can exclude the ones that are too short.

I would also want to include a column which can tell me the number of immobile episodes.

Here is some example data:

```
   time  speed  zone     animal   group  week  distance period isImmobile
     
1  5.26  73.8 interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      50.3   p1     FALSE     
2  5.29  70.8 interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      1.30   p1     FALSE     
3  5.33  70   interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      1.40   p1     TRUE
4  5.36  56.3 interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      1.98   p1     TRUE     
5  5.39  51.7 interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      2.70   p1     TRUE     
6  5.43  47   interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      1.84   p1     FALSE
```

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
   time  speed  zone     animal   group  week  distance period isImmobile  Ep_number Ep _Duration
     
1  5.26  73.8 interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      50.3   p1     FALSE       NA        NA      
2  5.29  70.8 interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      1.30   p1     FALSE       NA        NA
3  5.33  70   interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      1.40   p1     TRUE        1         3
4  5.36  56.3 interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      1.98   p1     TRUE        1         3
5  5.39  51.7 interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      2.70   p1     TRUE        1         3
6  5.43  47   interzone  ctrl5    ctrl    0      1.84   p1     FALSE       NA        NA
```

The frame can also completely omit the episodes when isImmobile = FALSE rather than having NA.

Preferably dplyr but anything else is also good :)

Thank you so much in advance. I also hope a similar question hasn't been asked yet - I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `data.table` - use `rleid` on the 'isImmobile' column to create a run-length-encoding column, then using the 'grp' as grouping column, and specifying the logical column in `i`, we assign two new columns with group index (`.GRP`) and the number of rows (`.N`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(isImmobile)]
df1[as.logical(isImmobile), c("Ep_number", "Ep_duration") := 
   .(.GRP, .N), grp][, grp := NULL][]
```

-output

```
> time speed      zone animal  group  week distance period isImmobile Ep_number Ep_duration
   <num> <num>    <char> <char> <char> <int>    <num> <char>     <lgcl>     <int>       <int>
1:  5.26  73.8 interzone  ctrl5   ctrl     0    50.30     p1      FALSE        NA          NA
2:  5.29  70.8 interzone  ctrl5   ctrl     0     1.30     p1      FALSE        NA          NA
3:  5.33  70.0 interzone  ctrl5   ctrl     0     1.40     p1       TRUE         1           3
4:  5.36  56.3 interzone  ctrl5   ctrl     0     1.98     p1       TRUE         1           3
5:  5.39  51.7 interzone  ctrl5   ctrl     0     2.70     p1       TRUE         1           3
6:  5.43  47.0 interzone  ctrl5   ctrl     0     1.84     p1      FALSE        NA          NA
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rle`

```
cbind(df1, with(rle(df1$isImmobile), 
   data.frame(Ep_number = rep((NA^!values) * seq_len(values[values]), lengths),
    Ep_duration = rep((NA^!values) * lengths, lengths))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = c(5.26, 5.29, 5.33, 5.36, 5.39, 5.43), 
    speed = c(73.8, 70.8, 70, 56.3, 51.7, 47), zone = c("interzone", 
    "interzone", "interzone", "interzone", "interzone", "interzone"
    ), animal = c("ctrl5", "ctrl5", "ctrl5", "ctrl5", "ctrl5", 
    "ctrl5"), group = c("ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
    "ctrl"), week = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), distance = c(50.3, 
    1.3, 1.4, 1.98, 2.7, 1.84), period = c("p1", "p1", "p1", 
    "p1", "p1", "p1"), isImmobile = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
```